# two ngx-time-picker start time and end time are there, but 2nd one is showing same time as that of previous one, once start time is selected

Tags: javascript, angular, datetime, angular-material

timepicker.html

```
<!-- -->
<h2>ngx-mat-timepicker</h2>
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Start Time</mat-label>
  <input
    type="text"
    matInput
    [ngxMatTimepicker]="timepicker"
    [format]="24"
    [required]="required"
    readonly
    [formControl]="formControlItem"
  />

  <mat-icon
    matPrefix
    *ngIf="formControlItem.value && !formControlItem.disabled && !required"
    (click)="onClear('f1')"
  >
    close
  </mat-icon>

  <mat-icon
    matSuffix
    *ngIf="!formControlItem.disabled"
    (click)="openFromIcon(timepicker)"
    >schedule</mat-icon
  >
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>End Time</mat-label>
  <input
    type="text"
    matInput
    [ngxMatTimepicker]="timepicker1"
    [format]="24"
    [required]="required"
    readonly
    [formControl]="formControlItem1"
  />

  <mat-icon
    matPrefix
    *ngIf="formControlItem1.value && !formControlItem1.disabled && !required"
    (click)="onClear('f2')"
  >
    close
  </mat-icon>

  <mat-icon
    matSuffix
    *ngIf="!formControlItem1.disabled"
    (click)="openFromIcon(timepicker1)"
    >schedule</mat-icon
  >
</mat-form-field>
<ngx-mat-timepicker
  #timepicker
  [enableKeyboardInput]="true"
></ngx-mat-timepicker>

<ngx-mat-timepicker
  #timepicker1
  [enableKeyboardInput]="true"
></ngx-mat-timepicker>
```

timepicker.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
// import { DateTime } from 'ts-luxon';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  formControlItem: FormControl = new FormControl('');
  formControlItem1: FormControl = new FormControl('');
  // maxTime: DateTime = DateTime.local().set({
  //   hour: 16,
  // });
  // minTime: DateTime = DateTime.local().set({
  //   hour: 14,
  // });
  required: boolean = !1;

  @ViewChild('timepicker') timepicker: any;
  @ViewChild('timepicker1') timepicker1: any;

  /**
   * Lets the user click on the icon in the input.
   */
  openFromIcon(timepicker: { open: () => void }) {
    if (!this.formControlItem.disabled) {
      timepicker.open();
    }
  }

  openFromIcon1(timepicker1: { open: () => void }) {
    if (!this.formControlItem1.disabled) {
      timepicker1.open();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Function to clear FormControl's value, called from the HTML template using the clear button
   *
   * @param $event - The Event's data object
   */
  onClear(flag: any) {
    flag == 'f1'
      ? this.formControlItem.setValue(null)
      : this.formControlItem1.setValue(null);
  }
}
```

*I've selected start time as given below in image, while selecting start time, the default time was set to 12:00*
[image: start time image]

*once selected start time, I'am going to select end time, after clicking on watch icon when pop up gets opened, it must show default time 12:00, but it is showing by default same time as that of start time. So, Basically I want to set default time to 12:00 for both start and end time*

[image]

Comment: Better use https://npmjs.com/package/@dhutaryan/ngx-mat-timepicker